# uncaught exception: can't have . in field names

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to update a group of documents in my members_copy collection.

```
db.members_copy.find({"fields.shop.id": 321}).forEach(function(myDoc) {     
    db.members_copy.update({ "_id": myDoc._id}, { "fields.shop": [{"id": 319, "value": "Los Angeles"}] });
});
```

I get the following error:

```
uncaught exception: can't have . in field names [fields.shop]
```

I understand the problem, but I can't find a solution to this, so I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: So no way I can update a subdocument like this?

Comment: Do you have a fields sub-document in your target collection at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't have anything in your fields sub-document you can do this with [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/), which you should be using anyway if you have anything other than just `fields` as a field in your document.

```js
db.members_copy.update(
    { "_id": myDoc._id},
    { "$set": { "fields.shop": [{"id": 319, "value": "Los Angeles"}] } }
);
```

But what you can't do is add items to a sub-document without replacing the whole thing. So if you wanted to add `shop` where there was an existing `bar` you would need do this

```js
db.members_copy.update(
    { "_id": myDoc._id},
    { "$set": { 
        "fields": {
            "bar": "foo",
            "shop": [{"id": 319, "value": "Los Angeles"}]
         }
    }
);
```

Just a peril of using a sub-document in this way.